# Identify horror movie involving a ghost and a couple in a house

Tags: identify-this-movie

okay, I know the details are going to be extremely vague but if I had remembered better I wouldn't have to ask this now, so here we go, what is this movie's name?

1. It's an horror movie, there is a ghost in it.
2. safe to say that it's probably around 2 decades back.

the scenes/scenarios I remember are

1. a couple moves into a haunted house I think
2. The ghost also has like a burned body (this one not sure too)
3. The ghost grabs (or sort of hugs) the girl from inside the bed (or
   the mattress to be precise)
4. and oh boy this scene I remember very well, the girl looks outside
   the house at night and she sees someone(the ghost ofcourse) in the
   shadow and the ghost removes it's finger nails(long pointy) and
   blood comes out (the scene is happening in shadow)
5. this is probably the last scene, when the couple leave the house
   forever in a car, someone, a girl was standing in front of the door
   and the ghost grabs that woman inside the house through a round
   hole(covered with glass) in the door into the home!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds a lot like Nightmare on Elm Street:

- ghost would be Freddy Krueger who died in a fire and looked like it.
- Freddy kills people while they are sleeping, including one girl who he kind of pulls into her mattress, then blood flies up from bed.
- Freddy's weapon of choice is glove with knife-blades for fingernails.
- in final scene, a woman is standing on her porch in front of closed door, and Freddy's arm smashes through the door window and pulls the woman inside.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just now I checked the IMDB, apparently there are two versions, definitely not the 2010 one (I saw that movie in video cassette!), but may be it is 1984, but I haven't seen that so can't confirm, does the last scene I have described and especially the 4th scene I have mentioned happen in that 1984 film???

Comment: I can confirm that the scenes you list match very closely with the 1984 film.  In one scene Freddy Krueger terrifies Amanda Wyss's character by cutting off his own fingers resulting in spurting blood.  (In another scene he lifts his shirt and slices his own stomach.)  The film does end with Heather Langenkamp's mother being pulled into the house through a window.

Comment: just now checked it's trailer and I recognized the small girls skipping scene. yes this was that movie. Thanks